# Sound played slows down my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, avaudioplayer

I'm having this problem with playing sounds in my app. I used  AudioServices before, but problem was that first sound was played with leg of few milliseconds. Now I tried with AVAudio. But AVAudio slows down my app (or stops it for few milliseconds - probably it stops all timers that are making my objects moving). It is playing the first sound without leg, because I am using "prepareToPlay" but now i got this problem. Is there some way to prepare AudioServices to play?
Anyone some other idea?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i've used this for several apps: https://github.com/ymc-thzi/ios-audio-player

But depend if your app requires an interface.

This worked great for me.

Comment: Tnx. But i need more like for playing really short sounds, like 3 seconds.

Comment: Could tell a little about what you need it for? This would probably give an better indication for what u need?

Comment: I need to play sound when my object grabs a coin in a game... but sometimes those coins are one after another and sometimes there is some longer space between them. So when they are one after another the delay happens just when you grab the first one, when you grab others, there is no delay. Than if you must travel longer to next coin, there is again delay when you grab the first one. Like if phone would have my sound saved somewhere in memory for few seconds, after a while deletes it and when he have to load it again, delay happens.

Comment: It really works nice with AVAudio but why the millisecond stop happens?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem was that I was using the same thread for everything. So I used other thread for sounds and main thread works just perfect now.